# Access 2016 Form Query Issue

Tags: ms-access

The query grabs/obtains the criteria from a form.  The problem is I have one field that is supplied in the data table that has multiple items separated by a comma. They are called `Upgrade Codes`:

Example: `18AAA, 8AAA, 2GAA, 1EAA`

[image]

I am using `Like [Forms]![Service Action Report]![Upgrade Codes] Or Like "*" & [Forms]![Service Action Report]![Upgrade Codes] & "*"` in my query and it works all but also returns similar matches.

For example: `8AAA` Form query search would return all records with `8AAA` and also `18AAA` since `8AAA` is part of `18AAA` this is not the desired outcome, is their a way to just get all records with the Upgrade Code supplied in the Form?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Like [Forms]![Service Action Report]![Upgrade Codes] Or 
Like [Forms]![Service Action Report]![Upgrade Codes] & ", *" Or 
Like "*, " & [Forms]![Service Action Report]![Upgrade Codes] & ", *" Or 
Like "*, " & [Forms]![Service Action Report]![Upgrade Codes]
```

By including the `* ,` and `, *` in your query it actually looks like the following for a upgrade code value like `8AAA`:

```
Like "8AAA" Or 
Like "8AAA, *" Or 
Like "*, 8AAA, *" Or 
Like "*, 8AAA"
```

The differend "or" seperated statements work like follows:

1. `"8AAA"`:
   Full match of `8AAA` (there are no other values in the string)
2. `"8AAA, *"`:
   Match `8AAA` only if it is the first comma seperated value in the list
3. `"*, 8AAA, *"`:
   Match `8AAA` only if it is a middle value surounded by 2 commas
4. `"*, 8AAA"`:
   Match `8AAA` only if it is the last value

By including the boundaries *comma* or *beginning/end* of the string you ensure that only full codes can match.